# Sort bar chart by list values in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I am encountering an issue regarding the sorting my features by their value. I would like to see my image with bars getting shorter based on how high they are on the y-axis. Unfortunately, my barplot looks like this, with the features being sorted alphabetically:

[image]

Right now I am running the following code:

```
unsorted_list = [(importance, feature) for feature, importance in 
                  zip(features, importances)]
sorted_list = sorted(unsorted_list)

features_sorted = []
importance_sorted = []

for i in sorted_list:
    features_sorted += [i[1]]
    importance_sorted += [i[0]]
 
plt.title("Feature importance", fontsize=15)
plt.xlabel("Importance", fontsize=13)

plt.barh(features_sorted,importance_sorted, color="green", edgecolor='green')

# plt.savefig('importance_barh.png', dpi=100)
```

Here is the data going through there:

```
unsorted_list =  
 [('HR', 0.28804817462980353),
 ('BR', 0.04062328177704225),
 ('Posture', 0.09011618483921582),
 ('Activity', 0.0017821837085763366),
 ('PeakAccel', 0.002649111136700579),
 ('HRV', 0.13598729040097057),
 ('ROGState', 0.014534726412631642),
 ('ROGTime', 0.22986192060475388),
 ('VerticalMin', 0.016099772399198357),
 ('VerticalPeak', 0.012697214182994502),
 ('LateralMin', 0.029479112475744584),
 ('LateralPeak', 0.022745210003295983),
 ('SagittalMin', 0.08653071485979484),
 ('SagittalPeak', 0.028845102569277088)]

sorted_list = 
[(0.0017821837085763366, 'Activity'),
 (0.002649111136700579, 'PeakAccel'),
 (0.012697214182994502, 'VerticalPeak'),
 (0.014534726412631642, 'ROGState'),
 (0.016099772399198357, 'VerticalMin'),
 (0.022745210003295983, 'LateralPeak'),
 (0.028845102569277088, 'SagittalPeak'),
 (0.029479112475744584, 'LateralMin'),
 (0.04062328177704225, 'BR'),
 (0.08653071485979484, 'SagittalMin'),
 (0.09011618483921582, 'Posture'),
 (0.13598729040097057, 'HRV'),
 (0.22986192060475388, 'ROGTime'),
 (0.28804817462980353, 'HR')]
```

I recently upgraded to matplotlib 3.0.2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT** (based on the comments)

Your code works fine on `matplotlib 2.2.2` and the issue seems to be with your list naming convention and some confusion among them. It will work as expected on 3.0.2. Nevertheless, you might be interested in knowing the workaround

```
features_sorted = []
importance_sorted = []

for i in sorted_list:
    features_sorted += [i[1]]
    importance_sorted += [i[0]]

plt.title("Feature importance", fontsize=15)
plt.xlabel("Importance", fontsize=13)

plt.barh(range(len(importance_sorted)), importance_sorted, color="green", edgecolor='green')
plt.yticks(range(len(importance_sorted)), features_sorted);
```

[image]

**Alternative suggested by @tmdavison**

```
plt.barh(range(len(importance_sorted)), importance_sorted, color="green", 
     edgecolor='green', tick_label=features_sorted)
```

Comment: I think you can also use the `tick_label` option to `barh` instead of `plt.yticks`

Comment: @tmdavison: Thanks. I added your nice suggestion

Comment: What is the issue with matplotlib 3.0.2?

Comment: I don’t know but I believe the OP encountered some problem because the posted code works as such and producesthe desired plot in 2.2.2 but produces unsorted plot in 3.0.2. Can you try with 3.0.2 and reproduce the OP’s problem? Perhaps some bug?

Comment: No, there is no problem in any of the versions mentionned here. If anything, OP got mixed up with the various lists of the same name, or possibly they use a matplotlib version prior to 2.2.

Comment: Ok it seems 3.0.2 sorts the yaxis alphabetically in this case which is not the case for 2.2.2

Comment: No, 3.0.2 does not sort the axis.

Comment: Thanks a lot for adressing my issue, it works great! This may actually be something for the devs of matplotlib to get rid of.

Comment: I am a dev of matplotlib. What exactly is the problem? Your code runs fine. No need to use the workaround suggested in this answer.

Comment: Willem:  make sure you are using 3.0.2 and using the correct lists.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I just rebooted my laptop and it seemed to have resolved the issue indeed. False alarm sorry

Answer (score 1):

Searching an answer to the same problem, I came here, but how no answer satisfied me I create this simpler approach to sort any 2D structure like your list of tuples or a `dict_items` object to sort a dictionary:

```py
# Sorting a list of tuples by index 0 or 1.
unsorted_list: list[tuple[str,int]] = [('first', 1), ('third', 3), ('second', 2)]
sorted_list_by_index_0 = sorted(unsorted_list, key=lambda x: x[0])
sorted_list_by_index_1 = sorted(unsorted_list, key=lambda x: x[1])

# Sorting a dictionary by keys or values.
unsorted_dict: dict[str,int]] = {'first': 1, 'third': 3, 'second': 2}
sorted_dict_by_keys = sorted(unsorted_dict.items(), lambda x: x[0])
sorted_dict_by_values = sorted(unsorted_dict.items(), lambda x: x[1])
```

This approach allowed me to solve my problem in an attempt to display a `matplotlib.pyplot.barh` plot (an horizontal bar plot) with ordered bars using a dictionary containing frequencies of words.
Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

To avoid confusion from the other answer here, note that the code in the question runs fine and gives the desired output for any version of matplotlib >= 2.2.

```
import matplotlib
print(matplotlib.__version__)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


sorted_list = [(0.0017821837085763366, 'Activity'),
 (0.002649111136700579, 'PeakAccel'),
 (0.012697214182994502, 'VerticalPeak'),
 (0.014534726412631642, 'ROGState'),
 (0.016099772399198357, 'VerticalMin'),
 (0.022745210003295983, 'LateralPeak'),
 (0.028845102569277088, 'SagittalPeak'),
 (0.029479112475744584, 'LateralMin'),
 (0.04062328177704225, 'BR'),
 (0.08653071485979484, 'SagittalMin'),
 (0.09011618483921582, 'Posture'),
 (0.13598729040097057, 'HRV'),
 (0.22986192060475388, 'ROGTime'),
 (0.28804817462980353, 'HR')]

features_sorted = []
importance_sorted = []

for i in sorted_list:
    features_sorted += [i[1]]
    importance_sorted += [i[0]]

plt.title("Feature importance", fontsize=15)
plt.xlabel("Importance", fontsize=13)

plt.barh(features_sorted, importance_sorted, color="green", edgecolor='green')
plt.show()
```

[image]

The issue OP reports about is most probably caused by naming distinct lists by the same name and not restarting the kernel in between or similar non-reproducible things.